# Maximize the number of mood swings

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Sam has initially `k` apples. He then visits `m` shops. An array `arr` containing m values is given. At every shop he either buys or sells `arr[i]` number of apples. If he doesn't have enough apples to sell then he sells all he has. A number `N` is given such that if Sam has < N apples he is sad else happy. Whenever he has > N number of apples, he will always sell arr[i] number of apples. We have to sell or buy at each shop in such a way that his number of his mood swings is maximum.

`k` , `m` , `N` and `m` integers are given.

Whenever he has > N apples he will always sell but when he has <= N, he can either sell or buy that number of apples. We can't say that when he has <= N apples, buying will maximizing his number of mood swings.

I ran a recursive code but it gives a Timed out error and I'm not able to think of any other methods. Any help? Here is my recursion code as well.

```
 #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void fun(int *arr, int m , int l, int count, int &max, int k , int N)
{
if(l == m)
{
    if(count > max)
    max = count; 
}

else
{ 
    char state; 
    if(k  > N)
        state  = 'h';
    else 
        state = 's';
    char newstate;
    int prevk = k;
    if(k < N)
    {
        k+=arr[l];

        if(k  > N)
        newstate  = 'h';
        else newstate = 's';

        if(state != newstate)
            fun(arr,m,l+1,count+1,max,k,N);
        else fun(arr,m,l+1,count,max,k,N);
    }
   k = prevk;
    k-= arr[l];
    if(k < 0)
    k = 0;

        if(k  > N)
        newstate  = 'h';
        else newstate = 's';

        if(state != newstate)
            fun(arr,m,l+1,count+1,max,k,N);
        else fun(arr,m,l+1,count,max,k,N);

    k = prevk; 

}


}

int main()
    {
    int k,m,n;
    cin >> k >> m >> n;
    int *arr = new int [m];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
    int max = 0;
    fun(arr,m,0,0,max,k,n);
    cout << max << endl;

}
```

Comment: You're not asking us to do your homework for you are you?

Comment: No  @GordonM , actually I was asked this question in my recent placement test of Morgan Stanley. During test I used recursion and only 4 test cases passed out of 12. and I'm not able to think of any other method. So I was asking for an efficient approach.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is probably a verbatim homework dump, and in any event shows no attempt at a solution.

Comment: @EricJ.: I agree with you that even against the OP's claim of this being an interview question, it looks like a verbatim homework dump but the OP also mentions that an attempt to solve the question by recursive approach has been made. Assuming that OP is telling the truth, what more can be added to this question to improve its quality?

Comment: So... where's that approach?  Perhaps there is a simple reason for the "Timed out error".

Comment: Can you add the code you've written?

Comment: @Mansuro,  I have added my recursion code.

Comment: OK, looks like this question has been fixed to an acceptable standard for Stack Overflow now, so I'm prepared to withdraw my objections.  Just for the record, it's usually a good idea when writing SO questions to show what you've done in attempting to solve the question, preferentially with code along with expected and actual results.  The question as originally presented gave a poor impression, hopefully you've learned how to ask a good question now. ;)